# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Object[object Object] has no method slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the page url http://meracd.com/design/disc_designer.php?disc=cd

I've used jqueryUI for the slider. But it isn't working. I've loaded jquery and jquery UI before the custom.js script.

[image]

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question rather than just linking to a site that doesn't work, please.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have multiple instances of jQuery on your page.

Your jQuery UI Slider Plugin is attaching to `window.jQuery` (which is version 1.6.2), but your custom.js code is trying to run against `window.$` (which is version 1.6.4).

You need to either:

- Get rid of one of them (there's no need to have both)
- Alias the jQuery used in custom.js
- Use [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to resolve which jQuery gets access to the `$` variable.

Comment: I have removed the extra jquery and jquery ui scripts, now there's only a single reference to them. Still it in't working.

Comment: Because now the custom.js file starts with `jquery`, which should be `jQuery` (cap sensitive).

Comment: :D thanks @yahelc your suggestion worked, I replaced all instances of $ with jQuery and its running beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

You saved my day, in my case, adding noConflict() solved my problem

sample of my code

#

MVC 4

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>

jQuery.noConflict();
$(function(){
                 //  var $searchBox =  $("input#SearchString");
                   $("input#SearchString").autocomplete({
                       source: []
                   });
          });
```

Comment: Use `jQuery.noConflict();` before the start of your jQuery function to avoid conflicts with multiple (different) versions of jQuery files.

Comment: I too had the same problem.It worked great for me.Thanks a lot for the answer.@Feras

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that I had a similar issue and solved it by upgrading my version of JQuery. I had  a really old version on the site and by updating to the latest one the issue was resolved.